# Java: How can I use JSoup to read data from this website? And how do I find things like tags, and classes?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to read the pokemon name and coordinates from each column from this website (http://pokesniper.boosting-service.de/) to develop a desktop application that displays such data. I have never programmed in HTML.

This is all so new and complex to me, I have searched many tutorials, but they never explain how they got the element IDs, tags etc to specify what data they would like to print out. I know about inspect element on web pages but I just don't know what to look for, so if you could please help me by making an example that prints out that data, which I can analyse to get an understanding of using JSoup it would be greatly appreciated.

Or if you're feeling generous you could also explain how you got the tags and IDs so I can learn faster and know for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

> Jsoup, a HTML parser, its “jquery-like” and “regex” selector syntax is
>   very easy to use and flexible enough to get whatever you want. Below
>   are three examples to show you how to use Jsoup to get links, images,
>   page title and “div” element content from a HTML page.

Basically, jsoup should only be used when you have large amount of editing to be made. Like if you want to give id to many `<input>` tags or if you want to read the data from an internet webpage.

This example from official jsoup website should help.
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

> This example program demonstrates how to fetch a page from a URL;
>   extract links, images, and other pointers; and examine their URLs and
>   text.
>
> Specify the URL to fetch as the program's sole argument.

```
package org.jsoup.examples;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String url = args[0];
        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
        Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

        print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
        for (Element src : media) {
            if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
                print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                        src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                        trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
            else
                print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
        }

        print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
        for (Element link : imports) {
            print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
        }

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }
    }

    private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Fetching http://news.ycombinator.com/...

Media: (38)
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/y18.gif> 18x18 ()
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/s.gif> 10x1 ()
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/grayarrow.gif> x ()
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/s.gif> 0x10 ()
 * script: <http://www.co2stats.com/propres.php?s=1138>
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/s.gif> 15x1 ()
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/hnsearch.png> x ()
 * img: <http://ycombinator.com/images/s.gif> 25x1 ()
 * img: <http://mixpanel.com/site_media/images/mixpanel_partner_logo_borderless.gif> x (Analytics by Mixpan.)

Imports: (2)
 * link <http://ycombinator.com/news.css> (stylesheet)
 * link <http://ycombinator.com/favicon.ico> (shortcut icon)

Links: (141)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com>  ()
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/news>  (Hacker News)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/newest>  (new)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/newcomments>  (comments)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/leaders>  (leaders)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/jobs>  (jobs)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/submit>  (submit)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/x?fnid=JKhQjfU7gW>  (login)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/vote?for=1094578&dir=up&whence=%6e%65%77%73>  ()
 * a: <http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/facebook_gets_faster_debuts_homegrown_php_compiler.php?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+readwriteweb+%28ReadWriteWeb%29&utm_content=Twitter>  (Facebook speeds up PHP)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=mcxx>  (mcxx)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1094578>  (9 comments)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/vote?for=1094649&dir=up&whence=%6e%65%77%73>  ()
 * a: <http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/msg/a65fbbc8effcd914>  ("Tough. Django produces XHTML.")
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=andybak>  (andybak)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1094649>  (3 comments)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/vote?for=1093927&dir=up&whence=%6e%65%77%73>  ()
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/x?fnid=p2sdPLE7Ce>  (More)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/lists>  (Lists)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/rss>  (RSS)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com/bookmarklet.html>  (Bookmarklet)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com/newsguidelines.html>  (Guidelines)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com/newsfaq.html>  (FAQ)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com/newsnews.html>  (News News)
 * a: <http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=363>  (Feature Requests)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com>  (Y Combinator)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com/w2010.html>  (Apply)
 * a: <http://ycombinator.com/lib.html>  (Library)
 * a: <http://www.webmynd.com/html/hackernews.html>  ()
 * a: <http://mixpanel.com/?from=yc>  ()
```